# how to put json formatted data in div

Tags: json, node.js

Hi guys i written some codes in node.js and have some data in text file with Json format and i want to put them in div but i don't have any output and my codes have wrong part here: "var curServer = serverData[server];" and also how to get IP and ports from data and i don't know how to fix that
can someone tell me how to fix ?!

```
function populateServers(serverData) {

    for (server in serverData.servers) {

    var curServer = serverData[server];  // MY Problem IS here !!!

    $('#serverBasket').append(
    '<a href="pmiw4m://' + ipv4FromNumber(curServer.address) + ':' + curServer.port + '"> \
        <div class="serverHolder"> \
                <div class="serverPrimary"> \
                    <span class="hostname">'+ curServer.hostname + '</span><br /> \
                    <span class="map">' + curServer.mapname + '</span><br /> \
                    <span class="gametype">' + curServer.gametype + '</span><br /> \
                    <span class="players">'+ curServer.clients + '/' + curServer.sv_maxclients + '</span> \
                </div> \
        </div> \
    </a>' );
    }
}


$.getJSON("http://127.0.0.1/serevrlist/resopn2.txt", function (Response) {
    $('#subtitle h3').text("DEDICATED SERVERS");
    populateServers(Response);
});
```

resopn2.txt:

```
{  
"servers":{  
  "192.168.1.2:28961":{  
     "hostname":"PlusMaster-Test",
     "mod":"",
     "gametype":"DOM",
     "clients":"1",
     "sv_maxclients":"18",
     "mapname":"Crash",
     "players":[  
        {  
           "name":"MaximuM",
           "ping":"999",
           "score":"0"
        }
     ]
  },
  "192.168.1.3:28962":{  
     "hostname":"PlusMaster-Test2",
     "mod":"",
     "gametype":"DOM",
     "clients":"1",
     "maxclients":"18",
     "mapname":"Crash",
     "players":[  
        {  
           "name":"MaximuM",
           "ping":"999",
           "score":"0"
        }
     ]
  }
},
"last_updated":"2016-03-03T10:07:12.929Z"
}
```

Comment: have you tried JSON.stringify and JSON.parse? 

var serverData = JSON.stringify(serverData); 

serverData = JSON.parse(serverData);

before the line: for (server in serverData.servers) {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make some changes. They are as below:

resopn2.txt:

```
{  
"servers":[  
  {  
     "ip_address" : "192.168.1.2",
     "port":"28961",
     "hostname":"PlusMaster-Test",
     "mod":"",
     "gametype":"DOM",
     "clients":"1",
     "sv_maxclients":"18",
     "mapname":"Crash",
     "players":[  
        {  
           "name":"MaximuM",
           "ping":"999",
           "score":"0"
        }
     ]
  },
  {  
     "ip_address" : "192.168.1.3",
     "port":"28962",
     "hostname":"PlusMaster-Test2",
     "mod":"",
     "gametype":"DOM",
     "clients":"1",
     "maxclients":"18",
     "mapname":"Crash",
     "players":[  
        {  
           "name":"MaximuM",
           "ping":"999",
           "score":"0"
        }
     ]
  }
],
"last_updated":"2016-03-03T10:07:12.929Z"
}
```

changes in function : populateServers

```
function populateServers(serverData) {
var serverData = JSON.stringify(test); 
serverData = JSON.parse(serverData);
for (server=0; server < serverData.servers.length; server++) {  

var curServer = JSON.stringify(serverData.servers[server]); 
curServer = JSON.parse(curServer);

$('#serverBasket').append(
'<a href="pmiw4m://' + ipv4FromNumber(curServer.address) + ':' + curServer.port + '"> \
    <div class="serverHolder"> \
            <div class="serverPrimary"> \
                <span class="hostname">'+ curServer.hostname + '</span><br /> \
                <span class="map">' + curServer.mapname + '</span><br /> \
                <span class="gametype">' + curServer.gametype + '</span><br /> \
                <span class="players">'+ curServer.clients + '/' + curServer.sv_maxclients + '</span> \
            </div> \
    </div> \
</a>' );
}
}
```

Hope it helps